# Integrating $\int{\frac{x\,dx}{x^2 + 3x -4}}$

Tags: integration, polynomials

I saw this "Beat the Integral" problem and wanted to be sure I was approaching it correctly.

The integral is $$\int{\frac{x}{x^2 + 3x -4}dx}$$

So I decide I want to decompose this, because it's a degree-2 polynomial in the denominator and a degree-1 in the numerator, so that'd be a go-to. Also, since the degree of th enumerator is one less than the denominator we can maybe treat this as $du/u$ which would imply a natural log, though we don't quite know that yet.

So we decompose: I know that $x^2+3x-4$ can be factored as $(x-1)(x+4)$.

That gets me

$$\int{\frac{x}{(x-1)(x+4)}dx}$$
so I can do this:
$$\frac{Ax}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+4} = \frac{x}{(x-1)(x+4)}$$
Which implies
$$A(x+4)+B(x-1) = x$$
and since the roots are at $x=1$ and $x=-4$, I can set it up like this:
$$5A = 1;-5B=1 \text{  and } A = \frac{1}{5}, B=-\frac{1}{5}$$

Leading to:

$$\frac{x}{5(x-1)}-\frac{1}{5(x+4)}$$
Which I can set up the integral like so:
$$\int{\frac{x}{5(x-1)}-\frac{1}{5(x+4)}dx}=\int{\frac{x}{5(x-1)}dx-\int{\frac{1}{5(x+4)}dx}}$$
I can now integrate by addition here  $$\int{\frac{x}{x-1}}dx=\int{\frac{x-1+1}{x-1}}dx=x+\int{\frac{1}{x-1}}dx=x-\ln(x-1)$$
And doing the same thing for the second term and bringing back my $\frac{1}{5}$
$$\frac{1}{5}(x-\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+4))$$

I suspect there is a further simplification I could do. On a problem like this I also saw it integrated as an arctangent, but that seemed needlessly complex? In any case I was curious if I did this correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't  add an $x$ along with $A$ in the partial fraction. This makes the remaining steps wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here it is an alternative way to solve it:

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{(x-1)(x+4)} & = \frac{(x-1) + 1}{(x-1)(x+4)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x+4} + \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+4)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x+4} + \frac{1}{5}\times\frac{(x+4) - (x-1)}{(x-1)(x+4)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x+4} + \frac{1}{5}\times\left[\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+4}\right]\\\\
& = \frac{1}{5(x-1)} + \frac{4}{5(x+4)}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's a bit simpler, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the denominator has two linear factors, you can set up your partial fraction decomposition as

$$\frac{x}{(x+4)(x-1)} = \frac{A}{x+4} + \frac{B}{x-1}$$

This implies

$$ x = A(x-1) + B(x+4) $$

So $A+B=1$ and $4B-A=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(A,B) = (\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{5})$.

This means that

$$\int \frac{x}{(x-4)(x+1)} dx = \frac{1}{5} \int \frac{4}{x+4} + \frac{1}{x-1}dx $$

Then you can continue from here.

This is my first response, so I would very much appreciate any feedback on formatting or other site etiquette I may be unaware of. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Its wrong ! the step $$A(x+4)+B(x-1) = x$$ is not true instead you should have $$Ax(x+4)+B(x-1)=x$$ As you can see we would then have to take $A=0$ and the purpose of partial fractions is gone

I prefer $$\frac{x}{x^2-3x+4}=\frac{1}{5}(\frac{1}{x-1})+\frac{4}{5}(\frac{1}{x+4})$$

another way is to write $x=l(2x-3)+m$ (because derivative of $x^2-3x+4=2x-3$) then we have $$\int \frac{x}{x^2-3x+4}=\int \frac{2x-3}{2(x^2-3x+4)}+\int \frac{3}{2(x^2-3x+4)}$$ which is easy

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, and thanks for spotting the misstep!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{x}{x^2+3x+4}dx=\frac12\int\frac{2x+3}{x^2+3x+4}-\frac{3}{x^2+3x+4}$$
$$I=\frac12\ln|x^2+3x+4|-\frac32\int\frac{1}{(x+3/2)^2+7/4}dx$$
then you can let $u=x+3/2,\,du=dx$ so you have $u^2+(\sqrt{7}/2)^2=\frac74\left((2u/\sqrt{7})^2+1\right)$ now let $v=2u/\sqrt{7},\,dv=2/\sqrt{7}du$ now you have an integral of the form:
$$\int\frac{1}{v^2+1}dv$$ which can be easily solved using the substitution $v=\tan(t)$

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition into partial fractions supposes   these are *proper* rational fractions, where the degree of the numerator is less than the *degree of the irreducible factor* in the denominator. When the given fraction has only simple poles, as is the case here, this means the numerator is a constant, and actually, there exists a formula for a simple pole $\alpha$ of the rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$: the coefficient $A_\alpha$ for the pole $\alpha$ is given by
$$A_\alpha=\frac{P(\alpha)}{Q'(\alpha)},$$
which leads to the decomposition
$$\frac x{x^2+3x-4}=\frac x{(x-1)(x+4)}=\frac 15\frac1{x-1}+\frac 45\frac1{x+4}$$
and the integral
$$\frac15\bigl(\ln|x-1|+4\ln|x+4|\bigr)+C=\frac15\ln\bigl(|x-1|(x+4)^4\bigr)+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int{\frac{xdx}{x^2 + 3x -4}}=\frac{1}{2}(\int{\frac{(2x+3)dx}{x^2 + 3x -4}}-3\int{\frac{dx}{x^2 + 3x -4}})=\frac{1}{2}(\int{\frac{(2x+3)dx}{x^2 + 3x -4}}+\frac{3}{5}(\int{\frac{dx}{x +4}}-\int{\frac{dx}{x -1}}))=\frac{1}{2}\ln{|x^2+3x-4|}+\frac{3}{5}\ln{|x+4|} -\frac{3}{5}\ln{|x-1|}+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln{|x+4|}+\frac{1}{2}\ln{|x-1|}+\frac{3}{10}\ln{|x+4|} -\frac{3}{10}\ln{|x-1|}+C=\frac{4}{5}\ln|x+4|+\frac{1}{5}\ln|x-1|+C$$